# Stack Question (Balanced Expression problem set)

Tags: c++

I have solved a problem set for a CPSC class where we have to implement a stack to check if an expression is balanced. For example, when a user enters {a}, the program would check if it has been properly closed and return true or false. My program is running accordingly, but only for char values such as. {, ( & and [. When I enter an input of (2(1+2)) it returns false. The algorithm makes sense and works, but I cannot seem to find the issue with my isBalanced function.

I could really use some help

```
#ifndef BALANCED_H
#define BALANCED_H

#include<string>


class Balanced {
  public:
  Balanced(std::string);
  bool isBalanced();
  bool isMatch(char c, char d);

  private:
  std::string expression;
};

#endif // BALANCED_H
```

```
#include "Balanced.h"
#include <string>
#include<iostream>
#include <stack>

Balanced::Balanced(std::string s) : expression(s)
{
}

bool Balanced::isBalanced()
{
  std::stack<char> b;

  for(unsigned int i=0; i < expression.size(); i++)
  {
    if(expression[i]=='{'|| expression[i] == '[' || expression[i] == '(')
    {
      b.push(expression[i]);
      continue;
    }

    if(b.empty() || !isMatch(b.top(), expression[i]))
    {
      return false;
    }

    else{
      b.pop();
    }
  }
return b.empty();

}

bool Balanced::isMatch(char c, char d)
{
  if(c == '{' && d == '}')
  {
    return true;
  }
  else if(c == '[' && d == ']')
  {
    return true;
  }

  else if(c == '(' && d == ')')
  {
    return true;
  }

  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```
int main()
{
  std::string s;
  std::string expression;

  std::cout<<"Welcome to balance expression program" <<std::endl;

  do{
    std::cout<<"Enter any key to continue or type 'Help' to display a help menu ";
    std::cout<<"You may also type 'Exit' to exit the program: ";

    std::cin>>s;

    if(s=="Help")
    {
      displayHelp();
      continue;
    }

    else if(s=="Exit")
    {
      break;
    }

    else{
      std::cout<<"Enter an expression: ";
      std::cin>>expression;
    }
    Balanced d(expression);


    if(d.isBalanced()!=true){
      std::cout<<"The expressions is not balanced";
      std::cout<<std::endl;
    }

    else{
      std::cout<<"The expression is balanced";
      std::cout<<std::endl;
    }

  }while(s!="Exit");

  return 0;

}

void displayHelp()
{
  std::cout<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"The purpose of this program is to check ";
  std::cout<<"if an expression is balanced ";
  std::cout<<"You will enter an expression and it will check to see if there is 
  closing ";
  std::cout<<"brackets. If the expression is balanced, then it will return true if 
  not ";
  std::cout<<"then the program will return false ";
  std::cout<<"You can enter as many expression as you like. If you like to exit 
  the program, ";
  std::cout<<"type 'Exit'"<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The issue is that you forgot ***The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming***: your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do. You have verified that your computer works correctly when the input has only `{([])}` characters. Yes, you seem to have told your computer, correctly, what to do when that's the only input. Your computer will ***not*** correctly handle any other character for the simple reason that there isn't a single line of code that tells your computer what to do, in that case. Just tell your computer what to do, that's all. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that your isMatch function will return false if the current character is not an open or close bracket, thus causing the whole thing to return false.